# Using links in HTML tables associated with the right table row/person/id in the database

Tags: php, html, mysql, tablerow

Im a begginer in the whole SO and programming enviroment, and here comes my first question(which i tried finding in here but with no luck so far..)

I have an html table that prints specific patients of the doctor that is active (in a simple web-application that i created). The doctor gets filtered using $_SESSIONS global var in php.

My problem is that i want to implement a few actions in the same HTML table that displays the patients, like view history (which is stored in a local DB table, from an HTML from using POST method) and create a new form for the same person.

I saw that providing the table with row.ids could be a solution, but my table isn't static, i woulda like for the user to have the option to add/delete patients..

Following is a sample of my code that displays the HTML table "Existing Patients" :

```
<table>
            <tr>
              <th>Patient Id</th><th>Patient Name</th><th>Phone Number</th><th>Email</th><th>History</th>
              <th>Add a Follow Up Visit</th><th>Remove Patient</th>
            </tr>
            <?php  $sql = "SELECT * FROM patients WHERE Doctor_ID = $usersid";
            $result = $pdo->query($sql);
            if($result->rowCount() > 0){
              while($row = $result->fetch()){?>
            <tr>
              <td><?php echo $row['Patient_id']; ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $row['Patient_name'] ; ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $row['Phonenum'] ; ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $row['Email']; ?></td>
              <td><?php echo "<a href='/patienthistory.php'</a>" . 'Previous Visits'; ?></td> //problem here
              <td><?php echo "<a href='/patientform.html'</a>" . 'Add Follow Up' ; }?></td> //and here
            </tr>
</table>
```

I want the last 2 lines to connect immediately to the specific database stored *Patient_id* and retrieve the existing information stored there from the patients previous visits.

I hope i gave enough of a description, but if there is any more info neccesary, please let me know.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the patient ID as a query parameter in the URL that you're linking to. Also the HTML you're generating for your links is invalid currently. And the second link is going to need to go to a .php script, not a .html file, if you want it to execute code and fetch data.

Try this example:

```
<td><?php echo "<a href='/patienthistory.php?id='".$row['Patient_id']."'>Previous Visits</a>"; ?></td> 
<td><?php echo "<a href='/patientform.php?id='".$row['Patient_id']."'>Add Follow up</a>"; ?></td>
```

Then in each of the PHP scripts, use `$_GET["id"]` to retrieve that ID of the patient and use that in a query

e.g.

```
$patientID = $_GET["id"];
```

Comment: i modified the <td> lines as you instructed, and added the `$_GET ["id"]` on my .php files, but the id that it gets is null, i tried to echo it but no dice... i don't know if it helps, but in the patientform.php for my form i used the `$_POST` method... i also modified the query from `SELECT * FROM table` to `SELECT * FROM table WHERE patientID = $patientID;`

Comment: $_GET["id"] will be available when you first visit the page (which is always a GET, triggered from a hyperlink). it doesn't persist after you submit the subsequent form. You'd need to put the ID into a hidden field in the form, and then when you're processing the form submission (which would be separate to the code block you use to load the form) you'd be able to get it from $_POST